# Need to return "gmail_used_quota_in_mb" from user usage report with C# and Reports API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client, google-reporting-api

I am using the .NET client library on C# to build a small application for a specific purpose.

I need to return the value of 'gmail_used_quota_in_mb' and 'total_quota_in_mb', and 'used_quota_in_mb'

Based on this page (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-accounts) I should get the parameters in the output of the request of my application, however I am not getting those values...

I am doing it with the following code:

```
string nl = Environment.NewLine;
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        new[] { ReportsService.Scope.AdminReportsUsageReadonly },
        "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Reports.ListSizes"));
}

// Create the service.
var service = new ReportsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Reports API Sample",
});

try
{
    UserUsageReportResource.GetRequest request = service.UserUsageReport.Get("x@y.z", "2016-12-16");
    IList<UsageReport> result = request.Execute().UsageReportsValue;
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        AppendTextBox(textBox1.Text + "User ID=" + item.Parameters[0].StringValue);
        // In the Parameters[] array, I get 46 items, none of them is one of the above 3 parameters I am looking for...
    }           
}
catch(Google.GoogleApiException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
}
```

**In the Parameters[] array, I get 46 items, none of them is one of the above 3 parameters I am looking for...**

I took most of the code from the following page and I adapted it to fit my needs for UsageReport:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/quickstart/dotnet

I really appreciate any help, as mainly I am a systems engineer and I am working on a G Suite migration project and need to make this application to be able to do the critical part of data migration.

Edit (extra details): Here are all the parameters I get from the output...

> accounts:admin_set_name=xxxxx
>   accounts:is_disabled=
>   accounts:disabled_reason=
>   accounts:first_name=xxxxx
>   accounts:is_2sv_enforced=
>   accounts:is_2sv_enrolled=
>   accounts:is_delegated_admin=
>   accounts:is_less_secure_apps_access_allowed=
>   accounts:is_super_admin=
>   accounts:is_suspended=
>   accounts:last_name=xxxxx
>   accounts:num_authorized_apps=
>   accounts:num_roles_assigned=
>   accounts:num_security_keys=
>   accounts:creation_time=
>   accounts:last_login_time=
>   accounts:last_sso_time=
>   accounts:user_has_overridden_name=
>   docs:num_owned_google_documents_created=
>   docs:num_owned_google_documents_edited=
>   docs:num_owned_google_documents_trashed=
>   docs:num_owned_google_documents_viewed=
>   docs:num_owned_google_drawings_created=
>   docs:num_owned_google_drawings_edited=
>   docs:num_owned_google_drawings_trashed=
>   docs:num_owned_google_drawings_viewed=
>   docs:num_owned_google_forms_created=
>   docs:num_owned_google_forms_edited=
>   docs:num_owned_google_forms_trashed=
>   docs:num_owned_google_forms_viewed=
>   docs:num_owned_google_presentations_created=
>   docs:num_owned_google_presentations_edited=
>   docs:num_owned_google_presentations_trashed=
>   docs:num_owned_google_presentations_viewed=
>   docs:num_owned_google_spreadsheets_created=
>   docs:num_owned_google_spreadsheets_edited=
>   docs:num_owned_google_spreadsheets_trashed=
>   docs:num_owned_google_spreadsheets_viewed=
>   docs:num_owned_items_created=
>   docs:num_owned_items_edited=
>   docs:num_owned_items_trashed=
>   docs:num_owned_items_viewed=
>   docs:num_owned_other_types_created=
>   docs:num_owned_other_types_edited=
>   docs:num_owned_other_types_trashed=
>   docs:num_owned_other_types_viewed=

Thanks

Comment: try sending all  Get("all"   instead of a user.

Comment: I am working on this actually and I'm looking for a way to implement this...

Comment: what does "all" give you then?

Comment: Something I just noticed: when the user does not have any data the values I am after are not going to appear in the output!. I just want to confirm this...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if the user has no data at the time of retrieving the report the following values will NOT appear in the report:

- drive_used_quota_in_mb
- gmail_used_quota_in_mb
- gplus_photos_used_quota_in_mb
- total_quota_in_mb
- used_quota_in_mb
- used_quota_in_percentage

I guess that is an enough validation method for me, if the user has data the values will appear, then I can compare the data sizes. If the user has no data these values will not be returned and therefore I will assume data usage is 0 for him.

It took me a while to find out because the user who I was running the report against had data in fact, but because of the mechanics the reports data is available, I was searching in a time where the user had no data. When I put the 'all' search parameter, I got those values in some accounts who had data prior to the search date, and that made me more confused.

But today after being able to sit quietly and check each case, I came to this conclusion. I only wish it was pointed out more by Google on the parameters output page...